# changing position up and down in list through jquery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, html-lists

I am working on a list that changes position according to the button clicked.Here is a unordered list i had created and have contents like this

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;cat3_sub3</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div style="text-align:right;float:right;">
                [ <a href="#" class="up_sub" id="3_3">Up</a> ] 
                [ <a href="#" class="down_sub" id="3_3">Down</a> ]
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;cat3_sub2</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div style="text-align:right;float:right;">
                [ <a href="#" class="up_sub" id="2_3">Up</a> ] 
                [ <a href="#" class="down_sub" id="2_3">Down</a> ]
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;cat3_sub2</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div style="text-align:right;float:right;">
                [ <a href="#" class="up_sub" id="1_3">Up</a> ] 
                [ <a href="#" class="down_sub" id="1_3">Down</a> ]
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

now i want to change the list up or down as teh up or down link is clicked. so for this i wrote a javascript like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".up_sub,.down_sub").click(function(){
    var rank_id = this.id;
    rank_id = rank_id.split("_");
    var rank = (rank_id[0]);
    var cat_id = rank_id[1];
    var max_rank = get_max_rank(cat_id);
    if ($(this).is(".up_sub")) {
        if(rank!=max_rank){                                 //to not to move up than top most
            var thisLine = $(this).parent();
            var prevLine = thisLine.prev();
            prevLine.before(thisLine);
        }
    }
    });
});
```

but this didn't worked. i checked if it reaches inside the function using `alert()`. it gave response. But the list are not changing their position. what is the reason behind this. and what should be done to change the list position?

Comment: `get_max_rank()` get the maximum number of rank form the database. and `max_rank` is used for checking the top ranked `li` so that the values for rank is not changed in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('.up_sub').click(function(){
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    var prev = li.prev();
    if(prev.length){
        li.detach().insertBefore(prev);
    }
});
$('.down_sub').click(function(){
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    var next = li.next();
    if(next.length){
        li.detach().insertAfter(next);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NyRuX/)